# xelatex to html with hindi and roman languages

Tags: xetex, languages, html

I have the following set-up and I want a html file out of it. My system is windows xp with miktex up to date. The font `Gandhari Unicode`[link for the font](http://andrewglass.org/fonts.php) has all the symbols required and is installed on my system.

Xelatex compiles well, but the `htlatex` or `htxelatex` do not output anything, or if it does, it does not output a html file which displays the hindi font or the accents of the roman fonts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\makeatletter
%\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{devng4ht}
%}{%
%\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % ditto

\setdefaultlanguage{french}
%\setotherlanguage{hindi}
%\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=harvardkyoto]{Sanskrit 2003}
\setmainfont{Gandhari Unicode} %could be any Unicode font
%}

\begin{document}

«systèméÉÈ»; « systèméÉÈ » ¡²³³‘¤’€’‘³ øð¥‘‘ ©ç² æ\\
æááäåéþá×¥’ç‘¡¡³¤‘‘€’ç¾æ\\
¶ åé dans le  pāli: āsinῑ.

\emph{upasāka}

vipaśyanā

1 ◦

Prajñā

Ānāpānasati


is inquisitively enquiring about a man who is a composite for all merited endowments in his form and calibre. [1-1-1]\\  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use `alternative4ht` package for `tex4ht`. It is not in TeX Live yet, so you have to install it yourself with [helpersht](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht) packages. More info about this method can be found in [this guide](http://michal-h21.github.io/samples/helpers4ht/fontspec.html).

You have to modify your document slightly:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\makeatletter
%\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{devng4ht}
%}{%
%\usepackage{xunicode}
% \usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{alternative4ht}
\altusepackage{polyglossia}
\altusepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % ditto

\setdefaultlanguage{french}
%\setotherlanguage{hindi}
%\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=harvardkyoto]{Sanskrit 2003}
\setmainfont{Gandhari Unicode} %could be any Unicode font
%}

\begin{document}

«systèméÉÈ»; « systèméÉÈ » ¡²³³‘¤’€’‘³ øð¥‘‘ ©ç² æ\\
æááäåéþá×¥’ç‘¡¡³¤‘‘€’ç¾æ\\
¶ åé dans le  pāli: āsinῑ.

\emph{upasāka}

vipaśyanā

1 ◦

Prajñā

Ānāpānasati

मुक्त ज्ञानकोश विकिपीडिया से

is inquisitively enquiring about a man who is a composite for all merited endowments in his form and calibre. [1-1-1]\\  
\end{document}
```

Important lines are these:

```
% \usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{alternative4ht}
\altusepackage{polyglossia}
\altusepackage{fontspec}
```

compile the document using command

```
make4ht -ul filename.tex
```

and the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@michal.h21

I cannot add a comment to your reply, so I add an answer.
Both `xelatex` and `make4ht` compile well your document, but my `html` output is not at all like yours on windows xp. The accents on the roman letters are not displayed.

**HTML AND PDF WITH Gandhari Unicode**

Here is my `html`:

[image: html]

Here is my `pdf`:
[image: pdf gandhari]

There isa `रृ` missing on the pdf, but it appears on the html page.

**HTML AND PDF WITH Siddhanta**

the emphasis is lost on the pdf, but present on the `html`

[![html siddhanta][3]][3]

[![pdf siddhanta][4]][4]

This is the MWE that is displayed above:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{alternative4ht}
\altusepackage{polyglossia}
\altusepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % ditto

%  \setmainfont{Lato}
%  \setmainfont{CharisSIL-R.ttf}
%  \setmainfont{Siddhanta} %could be any Unicode font
\setmainfont{Gandhari Unicode} %could be any Unicode font
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=harvardkyoto]{Sanskrit 2003}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{hindi}

\begin{document}

«systèméÉÈ»; « systèméÉÈ » ¡²³³‘¤’€’‘³ øð¥‘‘ ©ç² æ\\
æááäåéþá×¥’ç‘¡¡³¤‘‘€’ç¾æ\\
¶ åé dans le  pāli: āsinῑ.

\emph{upasāka}

vipaśyanā

1 ◦

Prajñā

Ānāpānasati

\devanagarifont
मुक्त ज्ञानकोश विकिपीडिया से
\normalfont

is inquisitively enquiring about a man who is a composite for all merited endowments in his form and calibre. [1-1-1]\\

रृ


C'est en 1942 que nous avons connu cette technique que G. C. Lounsberry et M. La Fuente, fondatrices des \emph{Amis du Bouddhisme}, avaient rapportée de Ceylan, où Ānāpānasati était pratiquée et enseignée
```

Comment: I can compile your sample without display issues. It seems that your browser uses font without support for accented latin characters and without using fallback font for these, which is strange