# How to get Unicode characters into HTML output

Tags: unicode, tex4ht, characters, htlatex

I am trying to make a book in both print and ebook.   To make the print book I generate a PDF with xelatex.  I have reconstructed all the source files to be encoded in UTF-8 and the Cyrillic and Japanese characters are appearing correctly.

To get an ebook, you generate HTML.   For this I am using htlatex which appears to use TeX4ht to do the work.

```
htlatex "mybook.tex" "xhtml, charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

But when generating the HTML, I get errors in the log saying:

```
Missing character: There is no ½ in font cmr10!
```

It appears to complain that all the characters are not in the font, so it simply doesn't output the character.  However, we all know that browsers support these characters.

I don't really want to select a font, because I would like the HTML file to not specify the font -- I want to use the default font of the browser or ebook reader.  Yet, somehow I need to tell LaTeX to quit being so paranoid, and just go ahead and output the character anyway.  Is there any way to do that?

I have read other places that I need to select a "unicode" font.  With xelatex I use the `fontspec` package, but that is apparently not allowed by Tex4ht program.  (I get an error saying such).

I set the following in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

I suspect this is wrong since T1 means Latin1 characters?  I need Cyrillic and Japanese.  Anyway, when I do this, I get new error:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:┬Ñ not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Yes, it is not set up right.   So, my question is:  how do I select a font, or how do I otherwise convince htlatex to simply ALLOW all the characters to be written to the HTML file?

Here is a MWE that demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter

The flight was 4½ hours with a 3 hour change.  
We landed in Honolulu.  It was 85° and after 
rearranging the luggage which took a little time, 
ナンシースエンソン quickly got heated up.

\end{document}
```

my compile script is

```
htlatex "MWE.tex" "xhtml, charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

Comment: please ad a `mwe`. there is an experimental support for `fontspec` with `tex4ht`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280770/2891 and http://michal-h21.github.io/samples/helpers4ht/fontspec.html

Comment: Added MWE.  That is all there is to it.  The ½ character, and the ° character cause the compiler to go bonkers saying it is not set up for Unicode.  But the output is unicode HTML, so what do I do?

Comment: You can always use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `newunicodechar` package and then `\newunicodechar{½}{<definition>}` or `\DeclareUnicodeChar{<unicode point>}{<definition>}` for each character.

Comment: This should work around your issue partially https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445582/unicode-raw-binary-dump

Answer (score 3):

Your example doesn't work even with `pdflatex`, so it isn't really surprise that it doesn't work with `tex4ht` as well. Easiest solution to get non-european scripts working with `tex4ht` is to use [helpers4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht) bundle, in particular [emulation of fonstspec package](http://michal-h21.github.io/samples/helpers4ht/fontspec.html). `helpers4ht` aren't on CTAN yet, you need to [install it yourself](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht#installation).

Now back to your example, it is little bit more difficult because of Japanese, which needs to be handled by some package, like `xeCJK` for XeTeX or `luatexja` for LuaTeX. Both of these packages aren't supported by `tex4ht`, but we can load them using alternative package loader, which will suppress them when `tex4ht` is loaded:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{alternative4ht}
\altusepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
% \altusepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
% \setotherlanguage{japanese}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter

The flight was 4½ hours with a 3 hour change.  
We landed in Honolulu.  It was 85° and after 
rearranging the luggage which took a little time, 
ナンシースエンソン quickly got heated up.

\end{document}
```

You need to compile this example with LuaTeX as engine for `tex4ht`, for example with this command:

```
make4ht -ul filename.tex
```

LuaTeX is needed even if your document is normally compiled with XeTeX, because Lua callbacks are used to convert Unicode to suitable form for `tex4ht`.

The result

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I looks like your work is a huge benefit to the entire community.  I am having trouble with the install instructions: the first line fails (I have kpsewhich but it can't find any TEXMFHOME) and since I don't have a clue how all this stuff goes together I am not sure how to get around this.  It seems to make a copy of the GitHub files in a special subdirectory.  Can you tell me the rules around where I can place that folder?

Comment: @AgilePro if kpsewhich can't find TEXMFHOME, you can set it yourself: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71469/2891 it is special directory, where you can keep your personal packages and other files which can be used in TeX compilation

Comment: @mical.h21 Should this example above still work? I tried it with the `alternative4ht.sty` file from the `GitHub` but I failed with a lot of error messages.

Comment: @Ulrich it is not necessary to use `\altusepackage` for Fontspec and Polyglossia. It works if you use `\usepackage` for these packages instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.  Instead of

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

I need to use

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

UPDATE!

Too hasty.  That handles the one-half character and the degree symbol, it does not handle Japanese Katakana.