# tex4ht and Japanese font

Tags: tex4ht, japanese

A similar question and an answer can be found on
[How to get Unicode characters into HTML output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285871/how-to-get-unicode-characters-into-html-output) but I post a new question because the recommendation regarding my question there is not working for me.

If a run `make4ht -ul mwe-htjap` where this file contains the following lines

```
    \documentclass{article}
    %%
    \usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
    %% \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{english}
    %%
    \begin{document}

    The flight was 4½ hours with a 3 hour change.  
    We landed in Honolulu.  It was 85° and after 
    rearranging the luggage which took a little time, 
    ナンシースエンソン quickly got heated up.

    And now we are playing 囲碁
    \end{document}
```

I get a lot of error messages, e.g.

```
    [STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
    [STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: mwe-htjap
    [ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
    [ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
    [ERROR]   htlatex: /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-core.sty 180  Package luatexja Error: DVI output is not supported in LuaTeX-ja.
    [ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
    [ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
    [ERROR]   htlatex: /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-core.sty 180  Package luatexja Error: DVI output is not supported in LuaTeX-ja.
    [ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
    [ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
    [ERROR]   htlatex: /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-core.sty 180  Package luatexja Error: DVI output is not supported in LuaTeX-ja.

    ----------------------------------------------------

    (a lot more)...

    ----------------------------------------------------
    --- error --- Can't find/open file  `[/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/haranoaji/   HaranoAjiMincho-Regular.otf].tfm'
    [FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command tex4ht returned exit code 1
```

I am wondering about the last message, because running the file with `lualatex` gives no error but a correct `PDF`file.

Do I need a `htf`-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LuaTeX-ja doesn't play well with TeX4ht, as we don't support OTF fonts (this is what causes the fatal error `` --- error --- Can't find/open file  `[/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/haranoaji/   HaranoAjiMincho-Regular.otf].tfm' ``). So we need to suppress packages that tries to load OTF fonts. I've already fixed that in TeX4ht sources, but before you get the update in TeX Live, you can use the following `.4ht` files.

First is `usepackage.4ht`:

```
% usepackage.4ht (2022-09-14-19:39), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2003-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2022 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2022-09-14-19:39}

   \def\:temp{tex4ht}\ifx \:temp\@currname
   \:warning{\string\usepackage{tex4ht} again?}
   \def\:temp#1htex4ht.def,tex4ht.sty#2!*?: {\def\:temp{#2}}
\expandafter\:temp \@filelist htex4ht.def,tex4ht.sty!*?: %
\ifx \:temp\empty  \else
   \:warning{if
    \string\RequirePackage[tex4ht]{hyperref} or
    \string\usepackage[tex4ht]{hyperref} was
    used try instead, repectively,
    \string\RequirePackage{hyperref} or
    \string\usepackage{hyperref}}
\fi

\fi
\gdef\a:usepackage{\use:package ,!*?: }
\gdef\use:package#1,{%
   \if :#1:\def\:temp##1!*?: {}\else
      \def\:temp{#1}\ifx \@currname\:temp
             \def\:temp##1!*?: {\input usepackage.4ht  }%
      \else \let\:temp=\use:package \fi
   \fi \:temp}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{titlesec.sty}{titlesec-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{biblatex-chicago.sty}{biblatex-chicago-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{cleveref.sty}{cleveref-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{xr.sty}{xr-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{xr-hyper.sty}{xrhyper-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{eso-pic.sty}{esopic-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{showframe.sty}{showframe-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{expl3.sty}{expl3-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{savetrees.sty}{savetrees-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{newcomputermodern.sty}{newcomputermodern-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{newcomputermodern.sty}{newcomputermodern-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{fontawesome5-utex-helper.sty}%
{fontawesome5-utex-helper-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{fontawesome5.sty}{fontawesome5-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{biblatex.sty}{biblatex-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{xeCJK.sty}{xecjk-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{unicode-math.sty}{unicode-math-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{ctex.sty}{ctex-hooks.4ht}
\AddToHook{class/ctexart/before}{\input{ctexart-hooks.4ht}}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{luatexja.sty}{luatexja-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{luatexja-fontspec.sty}{luatexja-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{polyglossia.sty}{polyglossia-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{fontspec.sty}{fontspec-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{tikz.sty}{tikz-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{pdfbase.sty}{pdfbase-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{pdfx.sty}{pdfx-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{breakurl.sty}{breakurl-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{hyperref.sty}{hyperref-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{bookmark.sty}{bookmark-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{caption.sty}{caption-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{babel.sty}{babel-sty-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{minted.sty}{minted-sty-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{graphics.sty}{graphics-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{graphbox.sty}{graphbox-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{xcolor.sty}{xcolor-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{imakeidx.sty}{imakeidx-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{fancyhdr.sty}{fancyhdr-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{exerquiz.sty}{exerquiz-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{hyperxmp.sty}{hyperxmp-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{datetime2.sty}{datetime2-hooks.4ht}


\endinput
```

It contains instructions for packages that need special treatment, especially if they need to be handled at the moment when they load. The `\Configure{PackageHooks}{luatexja-fontspec.sty}{luatexja-hooks.4ht}` command will load the `luatexja-hooks.4ht` file before the package is used. We can block the package from further processing thanks to this file. This is how `luatexja-hooks.4ht` can look:

```
% luatexja-hooks.4ht (2022-09-14-19:39), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2022 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2022-09-14-19:39}

\:dontusepackage{luatexja}
\:dontusepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\endinput
```

The `\:dontusepackage` blocks the given package from loading. We block both `luatexja` and `luatexja-fontspec` here, as both of them cause fatal error with TeX4ht.

With this change, you should get the correct result:

[image]

Comment: @Jasper and Michal: It is working as mentioned. Great support.

Comment: @Ulrich I only corrected a formatting thing in michal.h21's answer. Credit should only go to them.

Comment: Can I have a "private" `usepackage.4ht` storing things which are disturbing the process? E.g. I am using `lucida-otf` and I would like to make the same as you with luatexja with the `Lucida` font. What I did:  

```
\ifdefined\HCode      
\usepackage{libertine}    
\else     
\usepackage{lucida-otf}     
\unimathsetup{partial=upright}   
\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO}    
\fi 
```

which is working. But are there other ways to solve this problem? And what is the meaning of `HCode` ?

Comment: I don`t understand why the code is not shown as code? In the .md file everything is ok.

Comment: It is better to report non-working packages, so I can fix them in the distribution. If you have your local version of usepackage.4ht, you would need to incorporate changes from the updates in TeX Live :/

Comment: OK, I understand. Then please add `lucida-otf` . see <https://ctan.org/search?phrase=lucida-otf>

Comment: @Ulrich I will. if you post new question, I can post the solution here.